# How to add static text into the form so it should be invisibly added to query of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla

For example i got a form "Search" and user searches "auto" how to make it search 
"auto sometext" ?

Im sorry for being such newbie. 
(i am using a 3rd party script, so i dont know how it works, and which file got the query function)

PS: It is hotspots for Joomla, im tryin to change direction form

Comment: On submit event of the form, modify the `val()` of the form field.

Comment: Add a hidden field with static text as value, it will be submitted with the form

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify the value of field before submitting (or modify the component to add value into search string)

for first option, you need to put in .js something like this:

```
$('#quick-search').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $search = $(this).find('input[type=text]');
    $search.val($search.val() + " sometext");
    $(this).submit();
});
```